# State entries total count in ethereum

Tags: synchronization, blockchain, ethereum, geth

What is the total count of state entries of ethereum blockchain currently? Currently my ethereum synchronization using geth shows 70 million processed state entries. Also I would like to know how much disc space will this take after all the state entries are done

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming

Comment: Also, it's >200m.